# EF code first cant connect to the db

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I followed [this post](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) step by step but when I'm running it and enter to the view I created I get:

> Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Ensure that IncludeMetadataConvention has been added to the DbModelBuilder conventions.

I dont know how to deal with it because I add Database.SetInitializer at the application_start and in the initializer I inherit DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges class, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you actually have the db created? Drop the db first to ensure its not there and let it create it and the proper model data should be initialized.

Comment: I did create it. I delete the db file and it worked! thank you!